# How to get full namespace path of model with asp-for

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am currently writing one-page checkout functionality for am e-commerce project. This functionality has Register and Guest tabs in a Form field and both have address fields like street, firstname, lastname, etc.. I am separating them by using a radio input

```cs
<input type="radio" hidden value="guest" asp-for="AuthModule.AuthType" />
```

This AuthModule class has both Register and Guest as class named "Register"

```cs
  public partial class AuthModule
  {
      public Register Register { get; set; }
      public Register Guest { get; set; }
      public string AuthType { get; set; }
  }
```

I also have a partial view named InvoiceAddress.cshtml in there I am using bunch of inputs for Firstname, Lastname, Street, etc... However I want this InvoiceAddress partial both available for Register and Guest which makes things messy like same inputs for different properties which makes validation hard, so I thought I can separete them by namespacing them like :

```cs
<label asp-for="InvoiceAddress.Firstname">@Localizer["deliveryAddressFormFirstname"]</label>
```

which outputs as :

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control is-required" id="InvoiceAddress_Firstname" name="InvoiceAddress.Firstname">
```

since both Register and Guest has the same Model given @model type in partial view results only InvoiceAddress.Firstname as input name but I need to make this name full path like **AuthModule.Register.InvoiceAddress.Firstname**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `for` attribute on `PartialTagHelper`:

```
<partial name="_InvoiceAddress" for="Register.InvoiceAddress" />
```